# ASP.net label control data bind color change

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, label

I am trying to figure out a way to change the color of the text display in a label control or span inside a user control.

The text needs to be displayed in a different colour based on the value returned.

```
<asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString()=="Flying Bats" ? "Display the text in green" : "Display the text in red" %> '/>
```

The text value would be one of the two. The font color needs to be ether red or green based on whats been returned.

I cannot figure out how to do it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try a little jquery:

Given your HTML as: `<span class='target'></span>`

A couple of simple CSS classes:

```
.text-red{color:red;}
.text-green{color:green;}
```

And a little jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tolerance = 5;
    $('.target').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() > tolerance){
            $(this).addClass('text-red');
        }else {
            $(this).addClass('text-green');
        }
    });
});
```

I would personally perfer using the data- attributes, but this will work provided the value in the span is a number.

In response to the comment:

```
<div> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass='<%# Eval("Name").ToString()=="Flying Bats" ? "text-green" : "text-red" %> '/></div>
```

Not my prefered method, but it should work.

Comment: <div> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString()=="Flying Bats" ? "Display the text in green" : "Display the text in red" %> '/></div>

Comment: Thanks.. I have the label or span inside a user control. Can you let me know how I can use jquery to achieve this in such scenario?

Comment: Updated the answer to answer using <%EVAL%>

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined to do it with server tags in the markup, I think you could use ForeColor:

```
<asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name").ToString() %>' 
ForeColor='<%# (Eval("Name").ToString()=="Flying Bats") ? "Green" : "Red" %>'/>
```

Or use a hexadecimal color instead of the color names, but you might have to use that ColorTranslator from System.Drawing. Not as familiar with C# so I hope I did the condition correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am probably not asking the right thing. And it seems pretty simple but I am stuck.The label text would have either a "Right" or "Wrong" returned from the database. And based on that value, I am trying to display the "Right" text in green....or if it  "Wrong, then simply display the label in red. Sigh.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. What exactly is being bound from the db? Is it an answer string or literally a string of the word "Right" or "Wrong?" And what do you want your label to say?

Comment: <div id="OrderHoldStatus" class ="clearfix">
                    <%# Eval("ProcessHold").ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains("released") ? "<span class=\"OrderHoldStatusItemReleased\">" : "<span class=\"OrderHoldStatusItem\">" %>                  
                    <%# Eval("ProcessHold").ToString() %>                 
                    </span>
                </div>

Comment: this is what I was trying to do :(. Could not figure it out myself